# Android Studio block log in feature implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication, timeout

I want to enhance my security feature of my android application. If the user attempt to log in and fails many times, I want to block the user for an hour. How can I implement this? My idea is create a static variable in log in activity to track the number of log in times, but How can I block the user logging again, use timeout or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two solutions:

**First:**

You can store some flag in SharePreferences. But user can clear data for your app (Settings->app->yourapp->clear data) and then SharePreference will lose value which result that user can enter in app.

**Seconde:**

Is to do sync with your server if you want to be 100% sure that user cannot enter in your app.

Static variable doesn't help you because it will lose value when user close your app.